# Issue with Normal Map in MeshStandardMaterial Causing Loss of Smooth Shading

Tags: three.js

I am currently working on rendering a model using the MeshStandardMaterial in Three.js. However, I’ve encountered an issue where the smooth shading effect on the normals disappears after I add a normal map.

Here is a screenshot without the normal map applied:
[a screenshot without the normal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OhMY.png)

And here is a screenshot after applying the normal map:
[a screenshot after applying the normal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3hTI.png)

I uploaded my textures to the Three.js editor and the result looked correct – the smooth shading appeared as expected with the normal map applied. However, when I use the same textures in my own code, the issue persists. This leads me to believe that there may be something specific in my implementation that’s causing the problem. Could there be a difference in how the Three.js editor applies the normal maps compared to a custom implementation?

Additionally, here’s a screenshot of the model as it appears in the Three.js editor, where the normal map seems to be working correctly with the smooth shading:
[the model in the Three.js editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfEJK.png)

Could anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I might fix it?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you provide sandbox?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz No sandbox! The code must be included as text in the question! See [Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @Rabbid76 (ㆆ_ㆆ)

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*

Comment: @Rabbid76  ( ͡ಠ ͜ʖ ͡ಠ)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I'll make sure to include my code in future questions for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to identify the issue—it was caused by setting the normal map's color space to sRGBColorSpace. When I switched it to NoColorSpace, the problem was resolved. However, I'm still struggling to understand why the smooth shading of the model is affected by the color space setting of the normal map. It's quite perplexing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).